# Customize CKEditor Classic

Tags: angular, ckeditor

How do I customize CKEditor Classic

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" id="Editor" [data]="editorData"></ckeditor>

import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
public Editor = ClassicEditor;
```

This doesnt seem to work I am trying using the below syntax as per their doc but it doesnt seem to work -

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#Editor'), {
      toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote'],
      heading: {
        options: [
          { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
          { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
          { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
      },
    }).then(newEditor => {
        this.Editor= newEditor;

      });
```

Comment: could you please prepare a stackblitz example to see what is happening? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckeditor-j8rog5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: even if you remove some from heading nothing really changes so not sure if classic Editor is customizable

Comment: after many hours time, I found out how to do, you can use @ViewChild or ChangeEvent to do that

Comment: was my answer your desired result or not? if not let me know. thx

Comment: You answered how to get the data from the ckeditor not customizing the editor like if I want to removed the bold and only have underline or remove the heading format etc....